# Passing arguments from variable - Python

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm writing a python script. In the script I wrote a function with some arguments that all has defult values. Also in the script i have list of tuples, first item in each tuple its the name of the argument from the function, the second is the value. here is code for example:

```
def f(a=0, b=0, c=0):
    print(a), print(b), print(c)

args = [('a', 12), ('c', -64)]
```

Is there some way, when I call the method, to put the value 12 in the 'a' argument and the value -64 in the 'c' argument without do it manualy? (the value b remains 0).

Thanks for any Help!

Answer (score 5):

You can build a dictionary then unpack it with `**`:

```
f(**dict(args))
```

will output

```
12
0
-64
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def f(a=0, b=0, c=0):
    print(a), print(b), print(c)

args = [('a', 12), ('c', -64)]

f(**dict(args))
```

result:

```
a = 12
b = 0
c = -64
```

But better way to use dict